# Non-overlapping navbar injection into webpages

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon

So, there is this Firefox addon called [Chlroine-HTTP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chlorine-http/) which puts a warning bar on Top of every webpage incase it's HTTP and not HTTPS.

But the problem is it overlaps the website on the top, just a little but that's annoying.

I want to make it so that it doesn't overlap the website and the website content(including the website navbar) is displayed below the chlorine-HTTP warning.

The problem is that other answers on SO are about manually diving the HTML body part into divs like header and content etc.

However in the addon it has to be injected into HTML of every webpage and I have to do this proccess automatically and not by manually editing the HTML.

Here is the code:

src/hacks.js

```
/* globals browser */

const t = browser.i18n.getMessage;

const removeWarnings = () => {
  const warnings = document.getElementsByClassName('chlorine-http-warning');
  for (const w of warnings) {
    document.body.removeChild(w);
  }
};

const addWarning = () => {
  if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost' || window.location.hostname === '127.0.0.1') {
    return;
  }

  const warning = document.createElement('div');
  const info = document.createElement('a');
  info.href = t('link');
  info.innerText = t('insecure');
  warning.append(info);
  warning.append('  ');

  const newLink = document.createElement('a');
  newLink.href = window.location.href.replace('http://', 'https://');
  newLink.innerText = t('trySecure');
  warning.append(newLink);
  warning.append('  ');

  const closeLink = document.createElement('a');
  closeLink.innerText = t('close');
  closeLink.style = { cursor: 'pointer' };
  closeLink.onclick = () => {
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName('chlorine-http-warning')[0]);
  };
  warning.append(closeLink);

  warning.className = 'chlorine-http-warning';

  document.body.append(warning);
};

removeWarnings();
addWarning();
```

Here is the CSS

src/style.css

```
.chlorine-http-warning {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
  position: fixed;
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 3px;
  width: 96%;
  left: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2147483647;

  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;

}

.chlorine-http-warning a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #FFF;
}

.chlorine-http-warning a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #BBB;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Do you have control of the Web Page (HTML), the Plugin Code, or neither?

Comment: @D.B. seeing as this is client side OP has control over everything. OP's problem is that they don't have the brains for it.

Comment: Hey @Darkrum, the OP knew to ask a question, that's the first step in learning.

Comment: @Darkrum I actually meant that the other answers mentioned expecitly and manually changing HTML to divide body into content and header etc. However I have to automatically do this using JS and CSS

Comment: @D.B.I have control over the plugin code and the website, I'm loading the plugin code using Firefox developer edition. I just don't know how to do it. Darkum is actually kinda right. But I want to make HTTP look bad even if it is with the help of others and also learn addon development at the same time.

Comment: I want to contribute to Open Source projects especially related to security, but I have several learning Disorders because I took traditional medicine which contains mercury and lead. I took gold ashes thinking it would heal me  not knowing they use Mercury and Lead https://youtu.be/XNo9NeMFAzc?t=1m3s

Comment: Why not then add something like this to your JS plugin code `document.body.style.paddingTop = "50px"`. Maybe right after `document.body.append(warning);` You may need to tweak the exact padding height accordingly.